# Java Regex : Replacing multiple words in jsps

Tags: regex, jsp

I am having Jsp code like -

```
<input type = "something" name = "something" value = "dto.value" />
```

Now I want to replace "input" with "form:input", remove name attribute, add new attribute "path" and set "name" attribute value to path such as my final output will be -

```
<form:input type = "something" path = "dto.value" />
```

How do I achieve it because I need to do this on over 250 jsps.

Comment: Your question will not be well received if you don't expose a specific point where you're stuck. You should probably pick up a regular expression tutorial and try to do it by yourself, you might earn valuable experience that you will be able to apply in the future.

Comment: Off course it will be too hectic to do it manually in each and every jsp.

Comment: Are you using an IDE such as Eclipse @GauravKamble ?

Comment: I am able to replace input to form:input and remove, but how can I set value to new path parameter while doing it. I am using Eclipse IDE.

Comment: @GauravKamble with a decent IDE (Netbeans or Eclipse for exampl) is a trivial job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did which does my job.

Find :

```
 <input([^>]*value=")(\$\{([^"]*)\})"([^>]*)
```

replace with :

```
<form:input$1$2 path="$3" $4/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse IDE, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to get `Find\Replace` pop-up window. Then check the `Regular expressions` check box. 
Use these Regex in the `Find` and `Replace with` textboxes respectively.

Find: `<(.*?)name\s*=\s*\"([^"]*)\"(.*)/>`

Replace with: `<form:\1 \3 path="\2" />`

Regex Explanation:

```
<               # starting of the tag
(.*?)           # group 1 - all the characters till the word 'name'
name\s*=\s*     # the word 'name' and '=' with spaces in between
\"              # starting of the name attribute value
([^"]*)         # group 2 - the value of name attribute
\"              # end of the name attribute value
(.*)            # group 3 - all the other attributes and values
/>              # end of the tag
```